# Can't Open Unity Link in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: unity-game-engine, wolfram-mathematica

[image: Can't open Unity Link]

When I try to get the unity link, it says that it can't open.  Any possible reason it would give this error? I am working from Step 2 here:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/UnityLink/workflow/ConfigureUnityLink.html

Edit: It may be to `$UnityExecutable` not being defined in mathematica.  How would I go about defining it?

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the documentation might be outdated.
Try [this](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/built-in-interface-to-unity-game-engine/seamless-and-automated-launch-process.html?product=language) and [this](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/built-in-interface-to-unity-game-engine/powerful-scripting-environment-for-unity.html?product=language).

Since v12, the way to start unity link after installing both Unity and Wolfram Engine is:

First, start with

```
Needs["UnityLink`"]
```

then there are two ways to open unity:

either open unity to check the version etc.

```
LaunchUnity[]
UnityInformation[]
CloseUnity[]
```

or open/create a unity project with wolfram engine called UnityProjectName

```
UnityOpen["D:\\unity projects folder\\UnityProjectName"]
CreateUnityScene["MyScene"]
CloseUnity[]
```